# Custom SelectAll checkbox only select elements from current DataTable page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a simple and basic DataTable which I added a thead with a custom SelectAll checkbox and another ones for each row existing in my tbody (I need to add this input because I'm attaching some data attributes, validations, events, etc. on it, based on the rows) that's why I cannot add the checkbox column on the .DataTable({}) config. At the moment everything it seems to work, the only problem is that my SelectAll event it's only working with element on the current page. Ex: If my datatable has 2 pages and I check my SelectAll input with the pagination located at page 1, all rows are selected but only on page 1. My question is if there is a way to handle this keeping the same functionality or what can I do to implement the selectAll without loosing the possibility to attach events to each row.

Here is my code and a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmexnp9h/)

```js
var ids = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "bSort": false,
      "order": []
    });
    
    $(document).on('change', '#chkAll', function () {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    });
    
    $('#btnCheck').on('click', function () {
        console.log(ids);
    });
    
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      ids.push(id);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnCheck">Check selected</button>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" /></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="1" /></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="2" /></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="3" /></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="19" /></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="4" /></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="5" /></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="6" /></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="7" /></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="8" /></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="9" /></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="10" /></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008-12-19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="11" /></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="12" /></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="13" /></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="14" /></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010-03-17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="15" /></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012-11-27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="16" /></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010-06-09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="17" /></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009-04-10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="18" /></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012-10-13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`rows` API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) to do that:

```js
var ids = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    const dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        "bSort": false,
      "order": []
    });
    
    $(document).on('change', '#chkAll', function () {
      //=> Loop over the rows:
      dt.rows((idx,data,node)=>{
        const $input = $(node).find("input");
        $input.attr("checked",!$input.attr("checked"));
        ids.push( $input.attr("data-id") );
      });
      //=> Loop ends here
    });
    
    $('#btnCheck').on('click', function () {
        console.log(ids);
    });
    
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      ids.push(id);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" id="btnCheck">Check selected</button>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" /></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="1" /></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="2" /></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="3" /></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="19" /></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="4" /></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="5" /></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="6" /></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="7" /></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="8" /></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="9" /></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="10" /></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008-12-19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="11" /></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="12" /></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="13" /></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="14" /></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010-03-17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="15" /></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012-11-27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="16" /></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010-06-09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="17" /></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009-04-10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-id="18" /></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012-10-13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Quick question... is possible to get all the checkboxes that are selected with a jQuery selector? Something like this: $('.check:checkbox:checked');

Comment: I don't think so, as they are not available in the DOM from what I see in the inspector.

Comment: Okay... I can handle that... Just one more thing, how can I handle the uncheck event?

Comment: I guess, loop over and uncheck the checked attribute.

Comment: Something like: $input.attr("checked",!$input.attr("checked"));